# How to debug XMonad.Layout.NoBorders.smartBorders not working?

Tags: xmonad, haskell

Since resetting my xorg.conf to use a second monitor, [`XMonad.Layout.NoBorders.smartBorders`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) no longer works: Even if there is only one window open on either monitor, and no docks, the main window still has a border.

Might anyone have an idea of how to proceed debugging? Such as by dumping the XMonad stackset to stdout? Thank you.

edit: Alternatively, assuming the implementation of smartBorders is incorrect or is having a strange interaction with other layoutHooks or I'm making an error, is there a quick-and-easy way to write a layoutHook which checks the XMonad stackset, checks if `length the_current_stack` (windows in the current screen) is 1, and then dynamically switches the layout to fullscreen (and vice versa if a new window is opened)?

edit: `noBorders` seems to work. Other modules such as the `smartBorder` flag in `XMonad.Layout.Spacing.smartBorder` have no trouble working in multi-screen mode. There seems to be a section in the code above at the bottom involving an 'Ambiguity' combinator.

Comment: I don't know what the stackset is, but it would help to post your xmonad config (and any other relevant config details, like your `xorg.conf`) somewhere.

Comment: The minimal test case is the default xorg.conf (with the second screen toggled on (Xinerama off)), and the default xmonad.hs (with `layoutHook = smartBorders some_layout`). It seems necessary to plumb the XMonad internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `X ()` that could be triggered via keybinding.

For example:

```
import System.IO

debugStuff :: X ()
debugStuff = withWindowSet (\ws -> do
    liftIO $ print ws
    liftIO $ logToTmpFile $ show ws 
  )

myAppendFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
myAppendFile f s = do
  withFile f AppendMode $ \h -> do
    hPutStrLn h s

logToTmpFile :: String -> IO ()
logToTmpFile = myAppendFile "/tmp/xmonad.log" . (++ "\n")
```

Bind `debugStuff` to a keybinding.

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to the standard library so this was quite helpful thanks.